# What new quests are available with the Dark difficulty level?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The manual for The Witcher 2 lists the various difficulty level, most of which seems to be pretty standard. The last one did catch my eye though:

> **Dark** – for very experienced gamers. This difficulty level allows you to acquire dark 
>   items and grants you access to quests which are not available on other difficulties.

Although it is *very* unlikely that I'll actually be able to play at this difficulty level, I am rather curious about what these quests and items are, and how they affect the story (use [spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/150097) as necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling them *new missions* is really a bit much. Basically, Dark Mode adds three new sets of equipment -  one in each act -  consisting of Armor, Boots, Gloves, Pants, and a Steel and Silver Sword. These items must be crafted -  the recipes are purchased from a vendor at a very high price, and the materials lists are *staggering* - and are 'cursed' - the swords will do damage to Geralt when used unless the full set of matched equipment is worn.

The 'quest' aspect comes from a token journal entry added with each set which weaves together a legend associated with the three sets of gear.

All of the information about the Dark Mode sets, including materials requirements, stats, crafting information and bonuses [can be found on the Wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Mode)